# Exec() php function dont work in linux empty request

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to execute this code on php in linux server

```php
$some= exec("node-v");
echo $some;
```

but i don't have an anwers

Comment: `$some= exec("node -v");`

Comment: i put " " but it still does not work

Comment: Errors? Messages? Output? Anything in logs? I've tested locally, works fine.

Comment: Anything if i put php -v works but if i put node -v dont works and if i put node -v on terminal works

Comment: How are you running this code? Via a web server? You still haven't told us what you _do_ get. You can also pass a third param to get the return code from the command, which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the comment above could not work than, maybe exec() is disabled. You can try to check `php.ini` file at `disabled_functions` line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec("node -v 2>&1", $output, $return_var);

echo $output;
print_r($return_var);
```